# Function not firing in mvc from jstree call

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this jquery that should fire the mvc function call,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert("ddddd");
$("#divJsTreeDemo").jstree({
    "plugins": ["json_data"],
    "json_data": {
        "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": "/WebTree/GetTreeNodes",
            "async": true,
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "dataType": "json",

            "data": function (node) {

                return ""; 

            },
            sucess: function (retval) {
                var d = "";
            },
            error: function (retval) {
                alert(retval);
            }
        }
    }

});

});
```

But i keep getting an error saying "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Am i getting the json wrong when i send it to the server?

Here is the mvc controller,

```
Public Class WebTreeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /WebTree

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

    Public Function GetTreeNodes() As JsonResult

        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        list.Add("dddd")

        'Dim jsonString As String = Encoding.Default.GetString(list.ToArray)

        Return Me.Json(list)

    End Function


End Class
```

Comment: try to send NULL in data, also make sure the url is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Enter the URL in your browser directly and see if you get results. If not, it may be a routing issue, but unlikely.
2. Use the browser's developer tools (press F12 in Chrome/IE) and inspect the request that is getting made. This problem is 99.9% of the time an URL issue.
3. Use @Url.Action() in your view to generate the path to the action, rather than a hard-coded link. The path may change depending on your deployment configuration.

Cheers.